# Array not being create from multiple checkboxes php

Tags: php, arrays, post, checkbox

I have a problem with a particular array in a checkbox input.

```
$insert .= '<tr>
<td>' .$uname. '</td>
<td>' .$fname. '</td>
<td>' .$lname. '</td>
<td>' .$email. '</td>
<td>'.(($admin == 'y') ? 'Admin':'User').'</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="change['.$uid.']" 
           value="'.(($admin == 'y')?'n':'y').'"/>'
                   .(($admin == 'y')?'Make a user':'Make an admin user').'</tr>';
```

From what i've been reading, this should create an array that can be run through if there are multiple checkbox. The $uid is the `user id` and the name displays as change[1], change[2] etc.. and this works.

The problem is when i run this through a while statement like so:

```
while(list($key, $val) = each($_POST['change'])) {
```

I get this message:

```
Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening and how to solve it?

Comment: try to print_r your $_POST['change'] to see what it holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is not being created when submitted.  I took your code and made the required form etc.

`var_dump($_POST['change']);` returns NULL, even when I remove the $uid.

I wish I could tell you why, but it looks like it 'should' work to me. 
I suggest cleaning up your code, taking out the ternary operators to something more aesthetically pleasing, then double checking your quotes.  PHP hates single quotes, even when they should theoretically work, like in the parameter of your POST array ('change') , it is possible the quotes are confusing it.

Well PHP doesn't hate single quotes, you just have to be careful with them as if they are used incorrectly it means code will not be parsed...

Comment: I think you're right. I've tried the other answers and some have worked but then stopped working again for no apparent reason. I'll have a change around in my code to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I went through again and found a submit button that i had accidentally set to the same name as the checkbox and that was throwing it all out.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the checkboxes should not contain an index value:

`<td><input type="checkbox" name="change[]" value="'.(($admin == 'y')?'n':'y').'"/>'.(($admin == 'y')?'Make a user':'Make an admin user').'</tr>';`

Answer (score 0):

```
//$uid is unique, so you perhaps might use this
// make sure $uid is set correctly
// This is correct for multiple checkboxes

<input type="checkbox" name="change['.$uid.'][]" ...
```

Comment: Yes, at least through each user: foreach ($_POST['value'][$uid] AS $this_user_data) {

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the checkbox name = change[]

And the value = $uid

Then you can iterate through $_POST['change'] and retrieve $uid

EDIT Remember that only the checked checkbox values are sent

Comment: So this did get rid of the message but it means i don't have the value that i had before, which was y or n, and i was trying to add into a database. Is there anywhere else i can put those values so i can still use them?

Comment: You need to have the uid of the user - is that right? The checkbox will return the uid if it's ticked and return nothing at all if not ticked. That should give you the information you need to write to the database.